# date conversion

Tags: apex

I have a date in visual force page as 31/07/2017 which I want to store in sobject field. so I did like this.

```
try
{ 
    if(!string.isBlank(fanDOB))
    { 
        system.debug('fanDOB'+fanDOB);
        fan.Birthdate__c = Date.valueOf(fanDOB); 
        system.debug('fsnBirthdate'+fan.BirthDate__c); 
    } 
    catch(Exception e)
    }
        system.debug('Error Occured'); 
    {   
 }
```

But it is not storing in the sobject field and when the page is refreshed its showing a previously stored value. Please let me know how I can move forward on this?

Comment: How are you saving this data?  Where are you updating `fan`

Comment: @eric, public String fanDOB { get; set; },   fan__c object has BirthDate__c of type Date. when the page loads I am fetching data like this: fanDOB=fan.Birthdate__c.format(); when I am saving data using command button I am saving as mentioned above.

Comment: I hope I am clear.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong above, although you don't need to have a try/catch .. But you need to post more relevant code

Comment: @eric, in vf page if I am giving the date as 31/07/2017 then it is not storing in the object field. I have given the updated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split it and create a newInstance of it.. I don't know of a easier way

```
String[] strDate = fanDOB.split('/');
Integer thedate = integer.valueOf(strDate[0]);
Integer themonth = integer.valueOf(strDate[1]);
Integer theyear = integer.valueOf(strDate[2]);
Date d = Date.newInstance(theyear, themonth, thedate);

fan.Birthdate__c = d;
```